# upload application to azure batch job failed while uploading from azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-batch

I am trying to upload an application to newly created azure batch account from the portal I followed below steps-

```
1) Created a azure batch account.
2) Create .zip of the application exe in local desktop
3) Go to the application options
4) Click on add applications 
5) Give applicationid, version and application package path by selecting the .zip from local machine.
6) Click on submit
```

Got different Errors-

- **ajaxExtended call failed**
- **Upload Error for ffmpeg.zip**
- **Upload block blob to blob store failed. Details: StatusCode = 201, StatusText = Created.**

Comment: Please note the size of the .zip is  <  22 MB.

Comment: This seems like probably temporary portal issue or something with storage, beacuse what I can see is that `Status=201` is **success** in terms to creation for **Detail** see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpstatuscode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8 . Probably would be worth it to try again, add screenshot or raise portal issue if this is happeing in your browser, given what youmentioned I tried this and was not able to see this specific error. thanks

Comment: yes the document reference created, but it's in pending state as not uploaded completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually when we upload a .zip file in this case it's failing, its better to use Azure Batch Explorer, its a desktop application.
https://azure.github.io/BatchExplorer/

Than you can easily add a package/ application to your batch account.

Also I was getting the same error when uploading a file to blob container from azure portal, so I used Microsoft Azure Explorer to upload and download the files.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me as well, and like Phil G, I noticed that a message was showing up in F12 developer tools that 'the auto storage account keys are invalid.'.  However, they were valid.

The problem was that I had turned off 'allow access from all networks' under firewalls and network configuration.   Changing this back to 'allow access from all networks' worked, at the tradeoff of security.

If relevant, I'm using a cluster with public access disabled, and user subscription pool allocation mode.

Comment: This was my issue and it's extremely unfortunate I've had to backtrack my security changes...

Answer (score 1):

I had a slightly different error and the message was very vague:

```
Upload Error for ffmpeg-3.4-win64-static.zip
File Upload encountered an unexpected error during upload.
```

Batch Explorer also failed to upload the file.
By looking at the network traffic in my browser I saw the POST request recieved a success 200 code, but looking inside the response JSON I saw the detailed error:

```
HHTP Status 409 - The auto storage account keys are invalid, please
sync auto storage keys.
```

I'd changed them a day ago, and had successfully used the new ones in a batch app, but in order for the batch account to automatically upload the application to the storage account they keys needed to be synchronized.
Quick fix was to sync the keys and all was good.

Comment: Hi Phil, I am new to Azure and adding an application to a batch account is my first activity. While trying to do so, I got the exact error that you mentioned in your comments. 
You mentioned that you looked at the POST request in the network traffic in your browser .
Could you please tell me how to do that ?

Comment: Hi @AnitMohanty on Windows in any Chrome based browser you hit F12, then navigate to the Network tab to see the traffic between your browser and the site.

Comment: HI @Phil, Thanks. I was able to check the response of the Post call. While trying to add an application to my Azure Batch Account, I also got a 409 response which read : " the managed identity does not have permission to access auto storage account. Please use Azure RBAC to assign the managed identity access to auto storage" .
As per a solution in Microsoft portal, I went to Access Control (IAM) of the linked storage account -> Checked access and added the assigned role of "Storage Blob Data Contributor" but it still did not work.
Any suggestion ?